# Separability of an algebra is equivalent to separability of its spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative C*-algebra.

**I would like to show that $A$ is separable (i.e. has a countable dense subset) if and only if the spectrum of $A$ (denoted by $\Omega(A)$) is separable.**

---

Notes and reminders:

A C*-algebra is a Banach algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with involution $*$ s.t. $\|x^*x\| = \|x\|^2$ for every $x \in A$.

Let me also remind that the spectrum $\Omega(A)$ is the set of the characters of $A$, that is  $\Omega(A)\mathrel{:=} \{\chi:A\to \mathbb{C} : \text{$\chi$ is algebra homomorphism $\neq 0$}\}$. Also note that the topology on $\Omega(A)$  is the weak* (or w$^*$) topology. So the closure of any set which indicates separability is also taken under weak* topology.

Comment: I tend to rather believe that it's equivalent to its spectrum being both metrizable and separable? (i.e., in the unital case, metrizable)? So a separable non-metrizable Hausdorff compact space, e.g., $\beta\omega$, could be a counterexample.

Comment: Don't enter and leave math mode for sets.  Namely, not $\Omega(A) :=$ {$\chi : A \to \mathbb C$ : $\chi$ is algebra homomorphism $\neq 0$} `$\Omega(A) :=$ {$\chi : A \to \mathbb C$ : $\chi$ is algebra homomorphism $\neq 0$}` but $\Omega(A) \mathrel{:=} \{\chi : A \to \mathbb C \mathrel: \text{$\chi$ is algebra homomorphism $\ne0$}\}$ `$\Omega(A) := \{\chi : A \to \mathbb C : \text{$\chi$ is algebra homomorphism $\neq 0$}\}$`.  I have edited accordingly.  Also, what do you mean by "the closure of any separable basis on $\Omega(A)$"?  Basis is coll'n of open sets, right?

Comment: @YCor - As far as i know the spectrum of any algebra as described is metrizable, so I don't understand why what you suggest would give a counter example (also it would be helpful if you could explain what is $\beta \omega$).

Comment: If you take the C*-algebra of bounded functions $\omega\to\mathbf{C}$ (i.e., of bounded sequences), the spectrum is the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\omega$, which is not metrizable.

Comment: @LSpice - thanks for editing, and what i meant was that if B is our dense countable set which indicates separability then the closure of it is taken in the w* topology. (maybe calling it basis wast smart).

Comment: @YCor - So there is something i don't understand (and correct me if im wrong) but doesn't then both the algebra and the spectrum separable - so where is the contradiction?

Comment: @nedgrekerzberg: Concerning you're last two comments: What do you mean by the weak${}^*$-topology on a $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: $\ell^\infty $ is not separable but its spectrum  $\beta\mathbb N $ is separable.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth this is what I wrote (with different notation: $\omega$ is the ordinal notation for non-negative integers)

Comment: @YCor Of course it is your example. I had the impression that the OP did not understand you.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you, you're right of course. Stupid typo. I'll delete my comment since the comments by you and Jochen Wengenroth, as well as Nate Eldredge's answer contain the same information without mistakes ;-).

Comment: In all this maze of comments, the very simple, elementary and well-known true necessary and sufficient condition for the separability of the algebra is missing. Here it is (for the unital case): $A$ is separable if and only if its spectrum is metrisable. The non unital case is easily deduced by using the standard ploys: adding a unit and taking the one point compactification.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true.

For simplicity, suppose $A$ is unital, so that its spectrum is compact Hausdorff.

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ is separable, then you can show that $X$ is second countable.  (Let $\{f_k\}$ be a countable dense subset of $C(X)$, and $\{U_n\}$ a countable basis of open sets in $\mathbb{C}$; then the countable collection of sets $\{f_k^{-1}(U_n)\}$ is a basis for $X$, using Urysohn's lemma.)  In particular, such an $X$ would be metrizable (by the Urysohn metrization theorem).

So the forward direction of your claim is true, since a second countable space is always separable, but this also suggests how to find a counterexample to the reverse direction: take a compact Hausdorff $X$ which is separable but not metrizable.  One standard example is $X = [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ with its product topology; considering it as the space of all functions from $[0,1]$ to itself, the set of polynomials with rational coefficients is dense.  Another, as YCor and Jochen Wengenroth discussed, is $X = \beta \mathbb{N}$, the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$.

The converse of the above statement is also true, as user131781 points out: if $X$ is a compact metric space, then $C(X)$ is separable.

So the correct version of your claim (including the non-unital case) would be that $A$ is separable iff $\Omega(A)$ is second countable iff $\Omega(A)$ is a separable *metrizable* space.

Comment: Thank you very much!